# Authorization - Claimset in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, claims-based-identity

I am migrating web API project from target framework `.net framework 4.6.1` to `.net core`. API needs authorization and used Claimset to get or set collection of claims from request in legacy project.

In legacy project, ClaimSet was used from `System.IdentityModel` library which is not available for .net core.

I tried by using `System.Security.Claims` library in .net core, but ClaimSet property is not available in this library.

My question, is there `ClaimSet` is available in .net core? if yes then, how should I used it? which library I need to consume to work with `ClaimSet` **in .net core**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no ClaimSet per se. You simply create an `Enumerable<Claim>()` now which is found in: microsoft.netcore.app\2.2.0\ref\netcoreapp2.2\System.Security.Claims.dll

Comment: This question I raised long back, I forgot what was work around for it. Still I will accept your answer as it is only answer for this question. **I have not tested your suggestions**